# Connecting to ldap securely for Dummies

Tags: php, ssl, active-directory, ldap, xampp

I have been struggling for days with no progress, to start with I have very little knowledge with LDAP and Active Directory. I need to use php to connect with an ldap server over an enterprise and then simply run a bind.

I went through a lot of material around this online but none seems to answer my question in an explicit manner. Besides, the error messages I receive are said to have many causes thus making it even tougher to target.

**Here's my current code**

```
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=allow');

$ldaprdn  = 'user'; // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps:\\localhost")
    or die("failed"); 

if (ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)) {
     echo "Using LDAPv3\n";
} else {
    echo "Failed to set protocol version to 3"; }

if ($ldapconn) {
    //ldap_bind() will fail without ldap_start_tls()
    if (ldap_start_tls($ldapconn)) {
        echo "LDAP TLS Started";
    }

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind OK";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind FAIL";
    }
}
```

This outputs "failed",

but if I change

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps:\\localhost")
//to
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("localhost")
```

This is the output

```
Using LDAPv3 
Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Can't contact LDAP server 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP_curater\index.php on line 18

Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP 
server in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP_curater\index.php on line 22
LDAP bind FAIL
```

**Some information about the project**

1. It will be hosted on an internal network at an enterprise level
2. All users are supposed to access it only from this internal network
3. For testing im currently running PHP on XAMPP,
4. Production will use a windows server with IIS

**Following are some of the things I'm trying to figure out**

1. How do I determine if the Active Directory needs to be connected on "ldap" or "ldaps"
2. Does "username" have to be just "username"? or "domain/username"
3. I read a lot about having to recompile php with open ldaps along with ssl for ldaps, as this is a xxamp stack, is it even possible, if yes how, if no, what are the alternatives
4. How exactly does one use ldap_connect() in this context,Does it need to be :

   - ldap_connect("localhost");
   - ldap_connect("ldap(s)://localhost");
   - ldap_connect("ad.orgsitedomain.com");
5. Is there any information I need to fetch from the Active Directory Team, if yes what would those be.

Do let me know if there's any more info you would need. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, as there no replies here's how I went about it.

Firstly and most importantly, if you're new to Active Directory, before reading up on any material download [Active Directory Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963907.aspx). You would have far more context about every aspect of Active Directory while researching your solution.

**How do I determine if the Active Directory needs to be connected on "ldap" or "ldaps"**

I really have no idea yet, just tried ldaps and ldap both seemed to work

**Does "username" have to be just "username"? or "domain/username"**

It has to be "Domain/Username"

**I read a lot about having to recompile php with open ldaps along with ssl for ldaps, as this is a xxamp stack, is it even possible, if yes how, if no, what are the alternatives**

Again I didn't have to do this, so really still not aware

**How exactly does one use ldap_connect() in this context**

It has to be ldap://DOMAIN atleast in my case

So once again, the only thing I really needed was Active Directory Explorer, the rest was all a piece of cake. Kinda wondering why this was not mentioned in all the tuts I came across